# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 - the installed does not detect any partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10.
I created the partition in Windows and installed Ubuntu in a USB using Rufus.

Then I accessed the BIOS to start from the USB and install Ubuntu.
When I restart and start installing it, I introduced the language, the wifi, and marked the "normal installation" option, but the next frame is this one:

[image: ubuntu_installation]

There should have been my partition made on Windows, but it is empty. If I click on "+" or "change" it just crashes, and just tells me "install Ubuntu is not responding".

Comment: First of all you do NOT create partitions for Ubuntu from Windows. From Windows you can shrink some existent partition in order to make room for Ubuntu and that "room" should be unallocated space, not a partition. Then the Windows Fast Startup feature should be disabled and some drive settings in UEFI aren't supported > SATA mode should be AHCI, RAID isn't supported. Please note that you if it's RAID you need to install AHCI drivers in Windows or it won't boot after the settings change. If this is too complicated for you, DON'T install Ubuntu, try it in a live session only.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't express myself correctly. I had shrunk the partition and all, but in SATA mode I had RAID. So I changed it to AHCI and it worked

Comment: For some reasons I can't explain right now Ubuntu 18.04 refused booting from USB and DVD for me just yesterday. I had to download 16.04 and it worked at first try. I upgraded to 18.04 after installing 16.04. I hope you can try that too and hope it works for you.

Comment: Please could you add hardware information to your question, and add your solution as an answer? It might help others with the same device

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please try to boot the Ubuntu installer with the option “Try Ubuntu”, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run the commands `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo os-prober`, [edit] your question and copy & paste the command output into it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The problem was the SATA mode option in the BIOS. It was set to RAID, and changing it AHCI made it work.

Hardware information of my pc (just in case you have the same):

LENOVO Ideapad 720s-14IKB
Intel Core I7-8550U Kaby Lake (Quad Core, 1.8GHz - 3.7GHz, 8MB Cache).
RAM: 8GB DDR4 2133MHz
Storage: 512G SSD M.2 PCIE